# User registration with autocomplete and create items

Tags: ux-field, registration

My registration is bid complex for not advanced users.
So basically how it works to register user need to choose country, city, club/studio, trainer/dancer
All fields except countries are **autocomplete** fields + they contain option to create item if not found then user need to press option "add city/club/trainer".

Challenge is that sometimes we've seen that users are stopping registration because after they typed cities they dont know what to do because form is blocked until user click "add city" and they just simply ignore that.

[image: City not found user should click new]

So my question is how to clearly show to user that item does not exist and they need to take action by pressing option add city

Comment: what is exactly your question?

Comment: @mike how to clearly show to user that item does not exist and they need to take action by pressing option add city

Comment: I've added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "add city" action is not recognisable as a CTA. There are two reasons: it is not expected to find a CTA in a dropdownlist, visualy the CTA is not recignisable as such.

Instead of show this option inside the dropdown you could close the dropdown an show the CTA below the input field. Something like this:

[image]

CTA's should be visually consistant throughout the whole application. so the chosen blue in my mockup would be wrong, since you use this already as Title...

Comment: This is what i was thinking but was not sure. So for now its the best solution. Should be clear to user

Comment: Just out of curiosity - how will one select "New City" in the drop-down if it's not on the list yet?

Comment: @Mike its autocomplete so user will type and app will filter to his needs as soon as there is no matches then i will show add button.

Comment: If you have the autocomplete list available, why not putting it in the drop-down already?

Comment: @Mike: As I understand, this is already the case but when there is no match left the dropdown still shows only the "add city" CTA which is not understood by user. And the last item in the dropdown hids the next input field. At least this is what I understood out of Voldoymyr's question. to voldymyr feel free to correct my interpretation.

Comment: @BrunoH yes you are right. This is what i think is confusing. User see "Add city" as an option and even can think that it name of the city....

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add an editable drop-down list, however it is not that obvious for less-experienced users.

I would go for an explicit solution if space is not at premium:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOWzic.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

However you run the risk that if you put official city names in the list only, like for example *Londonderry*, there might be some people who would explicitly type *Derry* only to show their origin. And while in fact the dancers come from the same location, on your site they will be categorised as coming from the different locations.
Unless you have the mechanism to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes i like @BrunoH idea because its actually one input as soon there is not option i can show message to user. And about cities yes we solved that problem by using merge. Because sometimes people type cities with mistakes.

Comment: Mike, surely _Londonderry/Derry_ mismatches will occur whether the drop-down shows only official names, or includes user-added ones? So long as you are _allowed_ to specify your own city name, you may get multiple variants of the same place (e.g. _Hull_ and _Kingston-upon-Hull_ in mainland UK)